# Macro Design - After Update Audit Trail (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access, audit-logging

I am new-ish to access scripting, but through brute force and the Uni of Google/Microsoft, I have been able to make some pretty nice DB's. I have two items that I am struggling with.

I am creating a AFTER UPDATE macro from the table that will track the changes to the fields and create a new table with the changes "old" and "new" values. So far it works well for the most part, but I am trying to two specific things:

1 - capture the value from a CBO and not the ID number.

2 - run a function from my VBA script.

For the item #1 here is a sample of my code from the macro designer for a CBO value. (sorry don't know how to add the code itself)

```
If [Eng_Units] <> [Old].[Eng_Units]
RunDataMacro
Macro Name = tbl_UnityExport.dmcr_AuditUnity
Parameters
par_Event = "Edited"
par_ID = [ID]
par_Field = "Eng Units"
par_OldValue = [Old].[Eng_Units]
par_NewValue = [Eng_Units]
End If
```

For the par_OldValue and par_NewValue, my Eng_Units comes from another table called tbl_Eng_Units but what is being returned is the ID of the tbl_Eng_Units or column(0) and not the actual text in column(1) of table. The table that is recording the changes is my audit table and as you can see, ID numbers don't help me understand what I have changed from and to, unless I actually go in a look at the id in my Eng_Units table

[Audit Record sample See #65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC4lX.png)

Can someone tell me how to get the textual value of the record and not the ID?

Item #2 I have another database that someone else developed and using a function in the "Value =" field of the SetField item. My function in a VB macro is called GetUserName(). and this is how it was written in the old DB. I am at a loss other than there is some other script I can't find...anywhere.

[Macro Designer for Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9qUR.png)

How would I run a function from the "Named Macro"

Your help and expertise is appreciated!

Comment: Questions should be focused and have only one topic - you have 2. Can macro recognize Column index? I will have to test. You can set a textbox ControlSource equal to the desired column (`=cboName.Column(1)`) and macro can reference that textbox. However, pulling 'old' value would require setting a variable (global or TempVar or textbox) when combobobx gets focus and have macro reference that textbox as well. Or use DLookup(). GetUserName() is not an intrinsic function so there must be code somewhere.

Comment: Maybe don't use macros. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html

Comment: Confirmed macro can recognize Column index. Either use a variable to hold 'old' data from column or use DLookup in macro for both old and new.

Comment: Thanks June7. You're right, sorry 2 questions. The macro is not in the VB script but macro builder. I will do some digging into the DLookup() from within the macro builder. All of my audit tracking is working except for two items, one being the entry of the Column(1) items vs the referenced ID number in a CBO. I could build a complex query, but if there was a way to just get that information, that would be great.

Comment: Second, the "GetUserName()" is a function that is build in the VB script area. It works, but within the macro build I can't seem to call that function. It works in another DB but perhaps I am missing something that other author put together in that DB.

Comment: I already described how to get descriptive info associated with ID. If GetUserName() function is in a general module, macro should be able to call it. You do not show attempted macro code nor what happens when trying to call - error message, wrong result, nothing? Perhaps you should post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.